# List a column value that has a certain number or great, referencing two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables named Project and Task. Check below for a portion out of the tables:

**PROJECT**

ProjectNumber     ProjectTitle

**TASK**

ProjectNumber     TaskNumber       Hours

I need to list all project which have at least 2 tasks, displaying the project number, how many tasks for that project, and the total number of hours worked on tasks for that project.

I'm not sure how to do this because there are multiple tasks for one project. Any information is appreciated. Thank you!

If the table is needed, I'm not sure how I can add it because I can't link websites. Also, this is in sqlplus.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
select
  projectnumber,
  count(*) as count_of_tasks
  sum(hours) as sum_hours
from
  task
group by
  projectnumber
having
  count(*)>1
```